# Keep track of character in string in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I Have a string as aabc. Now have to move character in string in circular way as

```
aabc--->abca-->bcaa-->caab
```

Now as we see that the first character a has been moved to 2nd position.
The problem is that the string can be rotated infinite no. of time but I have to keep track of 1st character.
Is there any way to do this

Comment: What do you mean you "have to keep track of the first character"?

Comment: In my example The first character is a.So after rotating the character circular way in a string . I have to find the position of the given 1st character that i.e a. I am just asking that is it possible to do it

Comment: If you know how many times it has been rotated, then yes. Else, No.

Comment: so basically knowing the no. of move  can do it

Comment: This sounds like something of an XY problem. Explain *why* you need to keep track of the first character and *how* you are rotating the string and we can give you a better answer.

Comment: @Roshanjha - Yes, if you know how many times it has been rotated, you can find out the original string and hence the first character.

Comment: rotating string in circular order

Comment: @Roshan are you always rotating it in the same direction?

Comment: @DeiAndrei Basically my problem was without knowing no. of move is it possible.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "write my code" site. Please try it yourself and come back if you have a concrete problem.

Comment: @UwePlonus If you read my post I am not saying to write the code. Just I was asking that if it is possible to do without knowing no of rotation

Comment: downvoters please let me know why downvote...So that I can keep in mind while asking question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the string can be rotated infinite no. of time but I have to keep track of 1st character.  Is there any way to do this.

In general, no.

Consider the string `"XXXX"`.  There is no way to tell the difference between the possible rotations of this string.  Therefore, you can't "keep track" of where the first character of the original string went.

Also, consider this string `"abcd"`.  There are 4 possible states that can be reached by rotating the string, but there is an infinite number of rotations.  You can "keep track" of the first character (`'a'`) ... by calling `str.indexOf("a")` ... but that doesn't tell you how many rotations were performed.  (The final position of the `'a'` tells you the total rotation modulus the length of the string.  But it can't tell you the total rotation, or the sequence of the individual rotations.)

Comment: yes that is the problem.So I think it is not possible

Comment: @Stephen so we can conclude that by only knowing the initial String and the String after an arbitrary number of rotations, we can find the index of the first char only if every state of the rotation is distinct, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple modulus operation to do it

Code:

```
int headPosition(int numberOfRotate, String val){
   numberOfRotate %= val.length();
   int pos = (val.length() - numberOfRotate)% val.length();       
   return pos;
}
```

Function headPosition will return the first character of the string after `numberOfRotate` rotations.

**Note**: without knowing about the number of rotation, I don't think you can solve this problem, for example, if the input String is `aaaa`, so we cannot recognize which is the first character.

Comment: In my above example no. of rotate is 3 and position of first character is 1.Which is not satisfied according to your code

Comment: @Roshanjha I see, so the rotation is a left rotation, I have updated my code :)

Comment: is it possible to find it without knowing no. of move

Comment: @Roshanjha no, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

`Without knowing the number of rotations`, it is possible if you keep the original indices in a separate array and perform the `same shift to the indices array too`.

Let `x`, be the input string and `arr` be the indices `array`.

```
int[] arr = new int[x.length()];

// fill the array with the indices.
for (int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
{
    arr[i] = i;
}
// for every move towards right, shift the elements in the array once towards right
int last = arr[arr.length-1];
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length-1 );
arr[0] = last;

// for every move towards left, shift the elements in the array once towards left
int first = arr[0];
System.arraycopy(arr, 1, arr, 0, arr.length-1 );
arr[arr.length-1 ] = first;


// Once all the iterations are done, the indices array will hold the original position
// of the elements in tact.

for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("original index is: "+ arr[i]+" of "+ x.charAt(arr[i]));
}
```